# Tracking Multiple Google Analytics Conversions

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, conversion-specifier

For our recruiting website we have unique urls for each of our employees connected to their employee numbers. Then they are able to give out their unique URL to their personalized page. Wanting to know if there is an easy/best way to track how many submissions each employee's form generates. i.e. Todd has had 20 form submissions through his unique URL, etc.

Comment: You can do this with events. There you can send the url or number to analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the employee ID into a **custom dimension** (user scope) to link goals (submissions) to respective employees. This way you may also capture the number of times the link was used (visits and users) thus enabling you to calculate the conversion rate (submission per User) from each employee.